# Como salvar um objeto (JSON) por cópia em Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, funções

Como armazenar o estado atual de um objeto json por cópia? Porque se eu salvar por referência perco a informação exata do objeto naquele instante da atribuição.
Exemplo de objeto:

```
var sessao = {"num":"1"};  var vetorSessoes = [];

function salvando(){
  var copia = sessao; 
  var vetorSessoes.push(copia);
  sessao.num = 2;
}

function teste(){
  console.log(vetorSessoes[0]); //deveria printar '1' ao invés de '2'
}
```

Para vetores, eu aprendi a usar o `.slice()`, como faço pra fazer essa cópia com objetos e especificamente json.

Comment: É importante entender que, nesse seu exemplo, `sessao` não é um JSON. Ele é um [objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics). O JSON é uma representação de dados que usa o formato dos objetos do Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Para uma cópia simples (*shallow*) de um objeto pode usar [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var copia = Object.assign({}, sessao);
```

Veja como já dá o resultado que espera:

```js
var sessao = {"num":"1"};  
var vetorSessoes = [];

function salvando(){
  var copia = Object.assign({}, sessao);
  vetorSessoes.push(copia);
  sessao.num = 2;
}

function teste(){
  console.log("Copia tem ", vetorSessoes[0]); //deveria printar '1' ao invés de '2'
}

salvando();
teste();
console.log("Sessão tem ", sessao);
```

No entanto isto não irá funcionar corretamente se tiver objetos dentro de objetos, como por exemplo:

```
var sessao = { 
    "num":"1",
    "casa": {
        "area": 110,
        "divisoes": 5
    }
};
```

Neste caso tem de fazer uma cópia profunda (*deep*), a qual pode fazer utilizando [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) e [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var copia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sessao));
```

Exemplo também desta versão:

```js
var sessao = { 
  "num":"1",
  "casa": {
    "area": 110,
    "divisoes": 5
  }
};    
var vetorSessoes = [];

function salvando(){
  var copia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sessao));
  vetorSessoes.push(copia);
  sessao.num = 2;
  sessao.casa.area = 90;
  sessao.casa.divisoes = 3;
}

function teste(){
  console.log("Copia tem ", vetorSessoes[0]); //deveria printar '1' ao invés de '2'
}

salvando();
teste();
console.log("Sessão tem ", sessao);
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou você incluir na `sessao` o valor de `num` se você quer apenas incluir o valor na array, que é o que parece ao printar `vetorSessoes[0]`:

```
var copia = sessao.num;
```

```js
var sessao = {"num":"1"};
var vetorSessoes = [];

function salvando(){
  var copia = sessao.num; 
  vetorSessoes.push(copia);
  sessao.num = 2;
  teste();
}

function teste(){
  console.log(vetorSessoes[0]); //deveria printar '1' ao invés de '2'
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="salvando()">Salvar</button>
```

Ou pode adicionar à array o objeto como JSON:

```js
var sessao = {"num":"1"};
var vetorSessoes = [];

function salvando(){
  var copia = JSON.stringify(sessao);
  vetorSessoes.push(copia);
  sessao.num = 2;
  teste();
}

function teste(){
  console.log(JSON.parse(vetorSessoes[0]).num); //deveria printar '1' ao invés de '2'
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="salvando()">Salvar</button>
```